# Simultaneous while loops ? PYTHON

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, counter, simultaneous

Currently the code below works, but I should have a disease factor and a population number trigger to go along with it. Basically the juvenile and seniles can be affected by disease, but only once the total population reaches a 'trigger point' set by the user. I'm not sure how to do this, as if I put an extra clause onto the while loop which the population does not satisfy, I could create another while loop to use, but then the generation/counter thing won't work.
By the way, the stuff at the beginning of the code is to do with the class stuff I'm using, just ignore it.

```
print ("This is where you run the python model")

adult_population = Gen0.adult_population
birth_rate = Gen0.birth_rate
juvenile_population = Gen0.juvenile_population
juvenile_survival = Gen0.juvenile_survival
adult_population = Gen0.adult_population
adult_survival = Gen0.adult_survival
senile_population = Gen0.senile_population
senile_survival = Gen0.senile_survival
disease = Gen0.disease
disease_trigger = Gen0.disease_trigger
generations = Gen0.generations

counter = 0


while counter < generations:

    new_juvenile_population = adult_population * birth_rate
    new_adult_population = juvenile_population * juvenile_survival
    new_senile_population = (adult_population * adult_survival) + (senile_population * senile_survival)
    new_total = new_juvenile_population + new_adult_population + new_senile_population

    print("Juveniles:" ,new_juvenile_population)
    print("Adults:" ,new_adult_population)
    print("Seniles:" ,new_senile_population)
    print("Total population:" ,new_total)

    juvenile_population = new_juvenile_population
    adult_population = new_adult_population
    senile_population = new_senile_population

    counter += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `while` loop just put the lines of code that account for the affecting of the disease inside an `if` block, otherwise do the usual population keep doing the normal population update during each iteration of the while loop, but keep them outside the `if` block.

```
if juvenile_population + adult_population + senile_population >= trigger:
    # account for the disease here
```

I am guessing this is what you asked for.